# Can one send data securely to a REST API endpoint

Tags: api, rest

Say I have an endpoint to create a username:

- `https://example.com/api/create_user/foo/1234/` or
- `https://example.com/api/create_user/?name=foo&token=1234`

Where username = `foo` and the api token is `1234`:

Surely since `foo` and `1234` is encoded in the URL, it is public? My research says TLS encryption only encypts the body because the DNS servers need to know where to route the request.

QUESTION: Does this mean it is not secure to post data to a REST API endpoint?

Disclaimer, I guess one could encrypt the data first before putting it in the URL, e.g.:

- Encrypt the name foo -> `FF8811A`
- Encrypt the token -> `AABBCCDDEEFF1122`

And then request `https://example.com/api/set_username/FF8811A/AABBCCDDEEFF1122/`, and then the server decrypts the parameters.

Comment: As a best practice, sensitive data should be passed as headers or in the request body, not in the URI. Web servers access logs (which contain the URI) are often stored as plain text!

Comment: @myron-semack, do you have any recommendation for solving the problem without the data being in the URL?

Comment: Tell the API provider to fix their stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With https, the client must first do a DNS lookup of the hostname (in your case, example.com), so this part of the URL could leak during this step*.  Also, the hostname may be sent in cleartext to the server in the SNI header**.

But, at this stage, the client and the server initiate a TLS session.  Then, the client sends the entire URL in the http request to the server.

So, to answer your question: in your examples, https://example.com/ could be seen by a passive observer, but everything in the URL after this is encrypted by TLS.

---

*Although this could be mitigated using DNS over HTTPS (DoH) or DNS over TLS (DoT).

**Although TLS1.3 has provisions for encrypting SNI